# T-SQL (AVG) every 10 row

Tags: t-sql, select, average

I have this table in my T-SQL database:

[image]

In this query I have this sample record:

[image]

Now I have more more entry.

I have this query:

```
SELECT 'ECG' AS NOME,
        V.TIMESTAMP as ORA, 
        CAST(V.Valore AS DECIMAL(21,20)) AS VALORE, 
        row_number() over (order by V.TIMESTAMP) AS CONTEGGIO, 
        V.ID AS ID_VALORE
        FROM AA_V_CARTELLA_CLINICA_VALORI_ECG V
        ORDER BY V.TIMESTAMP asc
```

This query extract all data, I want to change it to extract the data but doing a average of column "Valore" every 10 value. It is possible to do it ?

Comment: do you want _moving average_ every 10 rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@bircastri I hope I understood you well, but think you are very close. What you need is to create a group bucket based on the the CONTEGGIO so they belong into a bucket of 10 values (modulo) and find the average of that. See a mock up below:

```
DECLARE @AA_V_CARTELLA_CLINICA_VALORI_ECG TABLE (Id INT, VALORE REAL, TIMESTAMP  datetime)
INSERT INTO @AA_V_CARTELLA_CLINICA_VALORI_ECG
SELECT 31853, 0.049, '2018-08-02 10:14:42.837' UNION ALL
SELECT 31854, 0.157, '2018-08-02 10:14:43.837' UNION ALL
SELECT 31855, 0.151, '2018-08-02 10:14:44.837' UNION ALL
SELECT 31856, 0.055, '2018-08-02 10:14:45.837' UNION ALL
SELECT 31857, 0.035, '2018-08-02 10:14:46.837' UNION ALL
SELECT 31858, -0.013, '2018-08-02 10:14:47.837' UNION ALL
SELECT 31859, -0.004, '2018-08-02 10:14:48.837' UNION ALL
SELECT 31860, -0.035, '2018-08-02 10:14:49.837' UNION ALL
SELECT 31861, -0.0032, '2018-08-02 10:14:50.837' UNION ALL
SELECT 31862, -0.031, '2018-08-02 10:14:51.837' UNION ALL
SELECT 31863, 0.049, '2018-08-02 10:14:52.837' UNION ALL
SELECT 31864, 0.053, '2018-08-02 10:14:53.837' UNION ALL
SELECT 31865, 0.061, '2018-08-02 10:14:54.837'







;WITH P AS(
SELECT 'ECG' AS NOME,
        V.TIMESTAMP  as ORA, 
        CAST(V.Valore AS DECIMAL(21,20)) AS VALORE, 
        row_number() over (order by V.TIMESTAMP ) AS CONTEGGIO, 
        V.ID AS ID_VALORE
        FROM @AA_V_CARTELLA_CLINICA_VALORI_ECG V
        --ORDER BY V.timestampc asc

)



SELECT  
    *, 
    GroupID=(CONTEGGIO - 1) / 10, 
    AVVALORE=AVG(VALORE) OVER ( PARTITION BY (CONTEGGIO - 1) / 10)
FROM P
```

Comment: @bircastri, see the modified version. I have added all other columns.

Answer (score 0):

If you want moving average, use below query.

```
SELECT *, AVG(VALORE) OVER (ORDER BY TIMESTAMP ROWS 10 PRECEDING) AS MovingAvg
FROM @AA_V_CARTELLA_CLINICA_VALORI_ECG
```

Comment: if I try to execute your query, I have this error: Incorrect syntax near 'ROWS'.

Comment: @bircastri, per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017, it should be supported since 2008.

Comment: Yes OVER clause is supported but the syntax I think that is not correct

Comment: I’ve run it on my SQL SERVER 2017 locally.